# Can DBID differ between nodes in a SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Group?

Tags: sql-server

I'm in a bit of a predicament. One of our client's has an availability group in SQL Server where the DBID differs between each node. For example, on the primary replica it's DBID is 23, however on the secondary it is 17.

It is required that DBID remains the same because of an application that utilizes it. I created a cluster in my environment and created 2 databases so far and I wasn't able to replicate their issue. I can't find anything else online about it either.

I'm starting to think that their cluster is not configured properly, however before pursuing that conclusion I'd like to know if any of you guys have experienced this before and how it could possibly occur?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, database_id (which is what the `DBID()` function returns) can differ between replicas in an AG. An AG, at its heart, is a collection of independent SQL Servers that manage a set of databases independently but in coordination with each other. That is, the data within the AG-managed databases (e.g. your user tables, stored procedures, etc) is synchronized between them but instance-level data (e.g. sys.databases, logins, Agent jobs, etc) are not. And since the assignment of database_id is one of those instance-level things, it's not synchronized between the participating instances in the AG.

I'm very curious what load bearing functionality relies on a specific database_id though. It is probably a lack of imagination on my part, but I can't think of anything that would require that.

Comment: Maybe it creates some sort of company id based on the database id? and things go downhill from there